# Encoding of German umlauts when using readOGR

Tags: r, encoding, rgdal

I'm trying to read an OGR vector map using the `readOGR` function provided by the `rgdal` package, but I'm having a little trouble with the German umlauts. I've provided a little example of what the data looks like, umlauts like **ö** are replaced with **\303\266**.

```
map <-readOGR("/path/to/data.gdb", layer = "layer")
map@data$name
# [1] L\303\266rrach
# [2] Karlsruhe
# [3] B\303\266blingen
# [4] ...
```

I've tried to specify an encoding in the `readOGR` function (`readOGR(dsn = "/path/to/data.gdb", layer = "layer", encoding = "UTF-8"` or `readOGR(dsn = "/path/to/data.gdb", layer = "layer", encoding = "LATIN-1"`), but it looks like it is ignoring the encoding parameter completely, since I'm getting the same result for each encoding I've tried. Does anybody know how I can get the `readOGR` function or R to display the correct German umlauts?

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: I'm running RStudio Server on a Debian 8 Server.

Comment: Very strange. I'm reading a geojson/shp file with encoding utf8 and the display in R is messed up. If I read the same data through a csv file using utf8 encoding (both exported from QGIS), everything is fine and dandy. Someone hand me a gun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what `encoding = "UTF-8/LATIN-1/..."` might do. I would have expected that you would choose one and only one encoding scheme. On my machine I do see the translation of that octal character to the o-umlaut:

```
> 'B\303\266blingen'
[1] "Böblingen"
> 'L\303\266rrach'
[1] "Lörrach"
```

To see the various conventions for R characters, type:

```
?Quotes
```

Besides encodings, there is also the need to have characters in the font being used. The font used in your console display doesn't seem to have the proper mappings for o-umlaut. My default font is Courier. You should also check your locale settings. `?Sys.getlocale`

Comment: I wanted to indicate that I've used different encodings while reading the OGR vector map. I've read it once with UTF-8, once with LATIN-1, etc.

As for your answer, that is kinda strange, I get different results.
`'B\303\266blingen' # "B\303\266blingen"`

Comment: That was the problem. Sys.getlocale() gave the info that currently "C" was used, I've changed it with Sys.setlocale() to a locale which supports UTF-8 and now `'L\303\266rrach'` is correctly displayed as "Lörrach".

Answer (score 14):

Julian is right.

```
file_name <- "../gis_data/bw/AX_KommunalesGebiet.shp"
shape_kommunal <- readOGR(file_name, layer = "AX_KommunalesGebiet", use_iconv = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")
data_kommunal <- shape_kommunal@data
head(data_kommunal)
```

returns the string correctly:

```
  GKZ                NAME
0 08236074           Kämpfelbach
1 08425052           Grundsheim
2 08435067           Deggenhausertal
```

Answer (score 6):

The encoding-parameter is ignored, if iconv is not set to TRUE.