# Umlauts in R not correctly displayed

Tags: r, character-encoding, diacritics, rgdal

I am trying to use multiple sources of German/Swiss data with umlauts in it. When trying to merge, I realized that the umlauts do not display correctly in R and the same names were rendered differently in different files.

```
map <-readOGR("/path/to/data.gdb", layer = "layer")
map@data$name
# [1] L\303\266rrach
# [2] Karlsruhe
# [3] ...
```

Along with several other posts, I read [Encoding of German umlauts when using readOGR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894867/encoding-of-german-umlauts-when-using-readogr/40469723) because one of my data sources is a shp file I read in with `readOGR`.

Appending `use_iconv = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")` to the end of `readOGR` did not help. And the problem exists outside of the use of `redOGR`. I saw that using `Sys.setlocale()` and a locale which supports UTF-8 worked for that poster, but I don't know what that means after looking at the `?Sys.setlocale` information.

How do I correctly read in German data in R on a Mac using English? `Sys.getlocale` reports C.

Answer (score 2):

Could you somehow include an exemplary .gdb-file?

What happens, if you try `encoding="latin1"`?

Maybe the gdb-data was saved in a wrong encoding? Are you creating it yourself, or you downloaded it from somewhere?

You could also check the information of the gdb-file with this command:

```
ogrinfo -al "/path/to/data.gdb"
```

Comment: Adding encoding="latin1" worked. Thanks! For the other half of the problem (the non-map data) I used Jan's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024654/reading-rdata-file-with-different-encoding. Both data sources used latin1. Could I set my work environment to use latin1 instead of converting all the data after the fact?

Comment: Also, I use RStudio. I tried the ogrinfo in the Console and got: `Error: unexpected string constant` and in the Terminal: `bash: ogrinfo: command not found`

Comment: You should use the ogrinfo command in a command-line. In RStudio it wont work. If it worked, I would appreciate if you check the answer or even upvote it :)

Comment: In the command line I get the error that the command ogrinfo is not found. I upvoted, but you +15 reputation for it to show. I am sadly at 1.

Comment: Then you are probably missing GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/). When installed, ogrinfo should work in the command line.

Comment: Correction: This solution worked in combination with `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.UTF-8")`